# Autohotkey script not working as intended

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use this script in autohotkey to make ctrl+shift+arrow key snap applications to one side of the screen in windows(normally windows key+arrow), but it only randomly works. Please help me find what I've done wrong?

```
^+Right::send, #{Right down}{Right up}
^+Left::send, #{Left down}{Left up}
```

Comment: try replacing `^+Right` with `^+R` (or any other key), if the problem goes away it means your trigger (the arrow key) was interfering with the command (which also contains an arrow key).

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem. And I have another script with arrow keys in both trigger and command working properly.
    `!^Right::send, #^{Right down}{Right up}`
    `!^Left::send, #^{Left down}{Left up}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
^+Right:: Send {LWin down}{Right}{LWin up}
```

or

```
^+Right:: SendEvent {LWin down}{Right down}{LWin up}{Right up}
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm